# Filebeat Kubernetes cannot output to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, filebeat

Filebeat Kubernetes cannot output to ElasticSearch,

1. ElasticSearch is OK.
2. filebeat is daemonset,relevant environment variables have been added.

**filebeat.yml**

```
filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: kubernetes
      node: ${NODE_NAME}
      hints.enabled: true
      hints.default_config:
        enabled: false
        type: container
        paths:
          - /var/log/containers/*-${data.container.id}.log

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
  username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
  password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
```

**Kubernetes**

Use nginx app to test:

image=nginx:latest

Deployment annotations have been added.

```
co.elastic.logs/enabled: "true"
```

[pod.yaml (in node1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ9sw.png)

But cannot output to ElasticSearch,Logs and indexes for related input are not seen.

[filebeat pod(node1) logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1Lpd.png)

Expect the filebeat to collect logs for the specified container(Pod) to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

@baymax first off, you don't need to explicitly define the property anywhere:

> co.elastic.logs/enabled: "true"

since filebeat, by default, reads all the container log files on the node.

Secondly, you are disabling hints.default_config which ensures filebeat will only read the log files of pods which are annotated as above; however, you haven't provided any template config to be used for reading such log files.

For more info, read: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-autodiscover-hints.html

Thirdly, in your filebeat logs, do you see any harvester being started, handles created and events published ? Posting a snapshot of logs doesn't give a clear picture. May be try starting filebeat in debug mode for few minutes and paste the logs here in proper formatting.